# How can I read a text file as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, text

I have a text file (not json) that looks like the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

How can I read it and put into 2 arrays: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']?

I'm using this to read the file:

```
jQuery.get('filename.txt', function(data){
 alert(data);
});
```

Comment: does the value in text file looks like `[a, b, c, d]` or `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`?

Comment: @ajaiJothi Oh shoot got it wrong in my post. It looks like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

1. split the string by multiline(`\r\n`)
2. loop through splitted array of string and replace the single-quote with double-quote to make it a valid JSON string
3. parse JSON string with `JSON.parse`

```js
const exampleData = `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`;

const multiLineTextToArray = (txt) => {
  return (txt.match(/[^\r\n]+/g) || []).map((line) => {
    // replace single quote with double quote to make it proper json string
    // then parse the string to json
    return JSON.parse(line.replace(/\'/g, '\"'));
  });  
};

/**
jQuery.get('filename.txt', function(data){
 alert(multiLineTextToArray(data));
});
*/

// example
console.log(multiLineTextToArray(exampleData));
```

**Solution 2:** constructing a valid JSON array

1. replace multiline(`\r\n`) with ','
2. replace single-quote with double-quote
3. wrap the whole string with `[]`
4. parse the JSON string with `JSON.parse`

```js
const exampleData = `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']`;

const multiLineTextToArray = (txt) => {
  return JSON.parse(`[${txt.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, ',').replace(/\'/gm, '\"')}]`);
};

/**
jQuery.get('filename.txt', function(data){
 alert(multiLineTextToArray(data));
});
*/

// example
console.log(multiLineTextToArray(exampleData));
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach to this would be the following:

data contains all the information from the .txt file. So I would try to read the file line by line using split function like this.

```
var arrays = []; 

jQuery.get('filename.txt', function(data){

var splitted = data.split("\n"); // --> should return an array for each line 

// Loop through all lines 
for(var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) 
{

var line = splitted[i]; 

// Now you could remove [ and ] from string  
var removed = line.replace('[','').replace(']','');

// Now you can split all values by using , delimiter
var values = removed.split(',');  
 var array = []; // this will be a single array

// Now you can iterate through all values and add them to your array
for(var c = 0; c < values.length; c++) 
{

var value = values[c]; 

// Now you can add this value to your array
// this depends on the data structure you are using in JS 
// for example
array.push(value);  

}

// NOw all values are stored in first array so add it to the multi array
// this is an array in an array
arrays.push(array); 

}

});
```

Comment: I like this but how do i add specific values to specific arrays?

Comment: each line contains the data for each array, you could use a multidimensional array with index i to store all the data.

Comment: Ahh so I can do something like `splitted[i].push(value)`?

Comment: You would need to define a own variable for this - I will add it in the code, but basically you are right

Comment: Wait I'm still confused. I need 2 completely separate arrays. If I did that wouldn't I just have an array with all the values inside of another?

Comment: No, you would have 2 seperate arrays stored in variable arrays, -> the output would be arrays[0] => array(a,b,c,d), and arrays[1] => array(e,f,g,h). so 2 different arrays but stored in one array.
You could also write it like this afterwards:

    var array1 = arrays[0]; 
    var array2 = arrays[1];

Comment: Ahhh completely understand now. Thanks for this, sorry I'm just a complete noob